# How to fix this webdriver script?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from time import sleep 
from tqdm import tqdm 

browser = Chrome('/home/mikhail/Desktop/WORK/kursach_2/die_Linke/chromedriver')
url = 'https://www.die-linke.de/start/presse/newsfilter'
browser.get(url)

posts = browser.find_elements (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.readon')
text = []
for post in posts:
    post.click()
    sleep(2)
    browser.back()
    sleep(2)
```

I'm trying to make a script which will click on a news post then go back and click on the next one. Everything goes ok until the second post: script crushes and error occurs. You may check it on your own. I think the problem is connected with CSS_SELECTOR, but I have already tried some different and nothing works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get a `StateElementReferenceException` if you try to interact with any element you found after a page load since finding the element, even if you return to the same URL. For this situation, get each `href` instead, and then go directly to those pages. Here's a simple solution that uses [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase):

`pip install seleniumbase` and then run the following script with `python` or `pytest`:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__)

class MyTestClass(BaseCase):
    def test_base(self):
        self.open("https://www.die-linke.de/start/presse/newsfilter")
        elements = self.find_elements("a.readon")
        hrefs = [element.get_attribute("href") for element in elements]
        for href in hrefs:
            self.open(href)
            self.sleep(2)
```

Comment: I've insalled seleniumbase through pip, but when i run the code the "name '__file__' is not defined" error occurs

Comment: Did you copy the code to a file first before running it? Eg. ``test_abc.py``? ``__file__`` only has a value if it exists in an actual file.

Comment: Yes, I have a file 'test_base.py' with the code you've sent me. The file is at the directory where my main code is

Comment: If you run that file directly with ``pytest``, you won't need the ``BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__)`` line. (It's only needed for direct ``python`` runs.